# How to reference Image Component in Next JS from Strapi API?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, strapi

How can I add a dynamic image from my Strapi API in NextJS. My other data I fetch without any issue. For my image I tried this but I get an error. Actually I just want to add the url (for the large titlePicture) after my localhost.

[image: Error after trying to add URL after Localhost]

[image: This is my JSON Object]

[image: Error after Compiling]

Comment: You doubling the curl bracket `${activity....}` instead of `${{activity....}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the key `titlePicture` is an array so you need to do:

`activity.titlePicture[0].formats.large.url` if you want the first object in the array.

Comment: and what do I have to do to get the second object in the array? I tried activity.titlePicture[1].formats.large.url , but it gave me an error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'activity.titlePicture[1].formats')

Comment: You need to provide the full JSON object for me to help you with that. But I would guess you only have one object in the titlePicture array or that the second array does not have a key called formats. @Ibo